# RSA Encryption-Decryption in iphone by Chilkat IPhone Objective-C Libraries

Tags: iphone, objective-c, chilkat

I am developing Iphone application. I have used Chilkat IPhone Objective-C . But i can't use this library for iOS 4.x and iOS 3.x  . I wonder if i Purchase Chilkat RSA License. Can this library be used in iOS 4.x and iOS 3.x?
Thanks!

Comment: My error when run in iPhone simulator 4.x is: "Library not loaded: /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib"

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to C++ runtime.

Please read [Chilkat IOS / IPhone Library Install Notes:](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/chilkatIos.asp)

In section **Must Link w/ C++ Runtime Libs**:

> The Chilkat internals are written in C++. Therefore, your Objective-C
>   application will need to link against the C++ runtime libraries. The
>   easiest way to do it is to include an empty source file with the file
>   extension "cpp" in your app target.

In section **Simulator vs. Device Static Lib**:

> There are separate static libs for targeting an actual IPhone/IPad
>   device vs. the simulator. Both libs are named "libchilkatIos.a". After
>   unzipping, the simulator version will be located in the "libSimulator"
>   directory, and the device version will be located in the "libDevice"
>   directory.